# Узнать возраст пользователя вконтакте api

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть ли метод, который покажет возраст пользователя?
Не дату рождения, а именно возраст?

Или придётся узнавать, сначала дату рождения, с помощью свойства bdate.
Потом выделить отдельно год и отнять его от сейчасного года?

Comment: 1) У контакта все методы API описаны. Есть там получение возраста? Даже не заглядывая могу сказать, что вряд ли, потому что 2) В чём проблема вычислить возраст по дате рождения?

Comment: А если год скрыт, что делать?

Comment: Значит пользователь не хочет распространять эту информацию, а значит и API тоже этого не хочет.

Comment: Нет такого метода. Вычислять через bdate.